# Django cryptographic signing security

Tags: django, security, cryptography

I'm planning on using Django's built in [cryptographic signing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/signing/) for an application I'm working on. All I need is the ability to sign + unsign a message, nothing more.

I'm assuming this is reasonably secure, as long as I salt my input correctly. Has anyone here ever had trouble with Django's signing? If they have, can they suggest an alternative?

Comment: That's a pretty vague question, but I *do* have an issue with Django using the word "signing" for a MAC calculation, and the non-existant word "unsigning" for verifying and removing the MAC. Just call it "verifyAndRemoveMAC" (expletive deleted).